# An expression for the function whose graph consists of the line segment from point to point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> An expression for the function whose graph consists of the line segment from (-2,2) and (-1,0) together with the top half of the circle with center the origin and radius 1.
>
> m=$\frac{0-2}{-1+2}$=-2
>   d=${\sqrt{((0-2)^2+(-1+2)^2)}}$=${\sqrt{5}}$
>   y=2x-2
>   ${x^2+y^2=r^2}$
>   ${x^2+y^2=1}$
>   ${y^2=1-x^2}$
>   ${y=\sqrt{(1-x^2)}}$
>
> do i need to add something more?

Comment: It should be $y=-2x-2$. See my answer below.

Comment: It helps if you tell what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a "piecewise defined function."

On the interval $[-2,-1]$ the function is defined by $y=-2x-2$ whereas on the interval $[-1,1]$ it is defined by the $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Accordingly the function can be expressed in the form

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
       -2x-2\text{ for }-2\le x<-1\\
       \sqrt{1-x^2}\text{ for }-1\le x\le1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Another way to express the function is using the $\textbf{unit step function}$

\begin{equation}
U(x)=\begin{cases}
0\text{ for }x<0\\
1\text{ for }x\ge0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
 f(x)&=&-2(x+1)U(x+2)+\left[\sqrt{1-x^2}+2(x+1)\right]\,U(x+1)\\
 &-&\sqrt{1-x^2}U(x-1)
\end{eqnarray}

However, this assumes it is defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ and equal to $0$ outside the given domain.

Here is a graph:

[image: Graph of piecewise function]